# Confusion about limit of log

Tags: real-analysis, logarithms

I have a very elementar question but I do not see where my mistake is.

Suppose we have a sequence $(x_n)$ with
$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=1$. Moreover, suppose that the sequence $({x_n}^c)$ for some constant $c>1$ has limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}{x_{n}}^c=c$.

Then
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\log({x_n}^c)=\log(c).
$$

But since $\log({x_n}^c)=c\log(x_n)$, I also have

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\log({x_n}^c)=c\lim_{n\to\infty}\log(x_n)=0.
$$

Where is my mistake? Maybe in the assumptions of the sequences.

Comment: So $d=1$. -----

Comment: How can it be that both $\;x_n\to 1\;$ **and also** $\;x_n^c\to d\neq1\;$ ? Of course, it can't ,and thus $\;d=1\;$

Comment: Sorry! I meant the limit is c.

Comment: By continuity of the function $x^c$ for all $c > 1$, it forces the limit of $a_n^c$ to be $1$, regardless of what $c$ is.

Comment: @mathfemi The limit isn't $c$. It would be if we were taking $\lim \log(c\cdot x_n)$, but we're not. Instead, we're taking $\lim \log(x_n^c)$. Note that when $x$ is very close to 1, $x^c$ is also very close to 1, and indeed $1^c = 1$ for any $c$.

Comment: @mathfemi what you have here is a perfectly good proof that the only way you can possibly have $\lim x_n^c=c$ is if $c=1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $x_n\rightarrow 1$, the only way to get $x_n^c\rightarrow c$ is if $c=1$. There is no other exponent $c$ which makes this work.

After all, if $x_n\rightarrow 1$, then $x_n^c \rightarrow 1^c = 1$ as well, by continuity (see below). But then if $1=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n^c = c$, then necessarily $c=1$.

So **you can't simultaneously have $c>1$ and $x_n^c \rightarrow c$** because this is a contradiction; anything derived from it may also be a contradiction. In particular, by continuity, $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\log(x_n^c) = c \log(1) = 0$ always. But if we assume $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} x_n^c = c$ and $c>1$, we find that instead $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\log(x_n^c) = \log(c) > \log(1) = 0$— a contradiction.

We assumed something that cannot happen, and got a contradiction as a result.

---

- First, note that if $h$ is any continuous function, then $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }h\left(x_n\right) = h\left(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }x_n\right)$$
- Next, let $f$ be the function $f(x) = x^c$, let $g(x)=\log(x)$, and suppose $x_n$ is a sequence such that $x_n \rightarrow 1$.
- Because $f$ and $g$ are continuous, we know that :
  $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \log(x^c) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} g(f(x_n)) = g\left(f\left(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} x_n\right)\right) = g(f(1)) = \log(1^c) = \log(1) = 0$$
- Because of the property of logs, we know that:
  $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \log(x^c) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} c\log(x_n) = c\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\log(x_n) = c \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}g(x_n) = c \cdot g\left(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}x_n\right) = c\cdot g(1) = c\cdot \log(1) = c\cdot 0 = 0$$

---

Taking a step back, we have that $x_n\rightarrow 1$, and because of continuity, $x_n^c \rightarrow 1$ as well. Hence $\log(x_n)$ and $\log(x_n^c)$ both go to 0 as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

If $\lim\limits_{n\,\to\,\infty} x_n =1$ then $\lim\limits_{n\,\to\,\infty} x_n^c = 1.$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\,\to\,\infty} (x_n^c) & = \left( \lim_{n\,\to\,\infty} x_n \right)^c & & \text{because } x \mapsto x^c \text{ is a continuous function} \\[10pt]
& = 1^c = 1.
\end{align}